# Only getting 200 as response for post String response in volley

Tags: android, string, android-volley

In my app, based on the customer requirement, I have to send a string parameter as a string response while in response, I will be getting another string from the server. I am using volley library for String post request. But in my onResponse(String response) method, printing the response only gives 200. I have checked the Post request on POSTMAN where can see the String response from the server side. I will post my code below. Is there anywhere I am going wrong? Need your help.

```
 try {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(myContext);
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("EmailID", "acacva@gmail.com");
        jsonBody.put("PassWord", "agaha");
        jsonBody.put("IsMobile", "true");
        final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();





        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, apiClass.API_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("afaga", response);
                Toast.makeText(myContext,response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
            }


            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody .getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString = "";
                if (response != null) {
                    responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                    // can get more details such as response.headers
                    Log.d("statuscode",responseString);
                }
                return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The response variable inside the OnResponse() just returns 200, POSTMAN shows the response as a string, eg:"hhdhbdwdbdhhddhbdb".

Comment: `responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);` you are setting response status code here, not the actual response. Change this to get body maybe?

Comment: I am getting 200 as response inside the below method:
 @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                   
                    Toast.makeText(myContext,response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your ***parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)*** Method you first parse the status code that is *200* and passed the value to the success method by calling ***Response.success(...)*** thus you getting the *200* status code in the Toast message.

you should call ***super.parseNetworkResponse(response)*** instead of ***Response.success(..)*** like below.

```
@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    //TODO if you want to use the status code for any other purpose like to handle 401, 403, 404
    String statusCode = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
    //Handling logic
    return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
}
```